# Is there a way to customize the default module initializer?

Tags: .net, initialization, c++-cli, static-initializer, clr-module-initializer

I am compiling an existing C++ library as a C++/CLI DLL.  The C++ library has two initialization routines which need to be called to set up various lookup tables.

The C++ library originally used `std::once_flag` and `std::call_once()` from <mutex> to perform one-time initialization of the lookup tables.  However, in C++/CLI, the <mutex> header is not supported:
[Error <mutex> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585714/error-mutex-is-not-supported-when-compiling-with-clr-or-clrpure)

I then tried using `std::atomic_flag` from <atomic>, but the <atomic> header is also unsupported in C++/CLI.

After seeing [Where do I initialize a managed C++/CLI DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335256/where-do-i-initialize-a-managed-c-cli-dll) I then tried implementing DllMain(), but I ran into the problem that the C++ library's initialization routines needed to call managed code.  In my case, I am not able to compile the initialization routines as unmanaged code (using `#pragma unmanaged`).

I then tried out a module initializer:

```c++
#pragma warning( disable : 4483 )
void __clrcall __identifier(".cctor")()
{
    InitLookupTables1();
    InitLookupTables2();
}
```

However, this causes 33 linker warnings of the form:

> 1>some.obj : warning LNK4210: .CRTMP section exists; there may be unhandled static initializers or terminators

I suppose that my custom module initializer is overriding a compiler-generated module initializer that properly runs all static initialization, such as setting global variables' initial values.

Is there a way to customize the compiler-generated module initializer or otherwise arrange to have the library initialization routines called by the compiler-generated module initializer?

Comment: Why don't you just use static initialization?  (Since you already are aware that the compiler-provided module initializer connects to that)

Comment: @BenVoigt:  Do you mean precomputing `InitLookupTables1()` and `InitLookupTables2()` and setting the values of the global variables affected to the results?