# C1189 #error: <mutex> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++-cli, mutex, unmanaged

I have a C++ library with managed C++ classes and unmanaged C++ classes, so the library is compiled with /clr support. I need to make some thread safe locking on the unmanaged side but if I include  I have the compiler error:

```
C1189 #error: <mutex> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure
```

How can I work around this? Spent a couple of hours searching but only found very old information. Using Visual Studio 2017 and C++11 language standard.

Comment: *"... on the unmanaged side"* - not according to the compiler switches you're using. You're compiling *managed* C++ code if you're compiling with /clr, whether you wish to or not. Your best bet would be to separate the unmanaged code from the managed into a separate DLL project, then either pinvoke or an rcw com-wrap to consume it. Alternatively, embrace the clr you're already using and just use the system threading monitor offerings.

Comment: Can't use the System::Threading::Monitor because it needs a common managed variable to lock into, and I can't declare a managed attribute in an unmanaged class.

Comment: There's also the [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/lock?view=msvc-160) class. But with /clr flag you really have full managed mode support, and can use managed attributes in "unmanaged" code.

Comment: The lock class also needs a managed variable to lock into, and I can't have it in my class if its unmanaged.

Comment: I'm using un unmanaged class because I'm calling a C++ unmanaged API and I thought it would have better performance. But maybe its nonsense because as you said, the code is already kind of clr. So probably the best solution is to use a managed class directly and use the lock clr class.

Comment: Duplicates: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821942/how-to-implement-a-unmanaged-thread-safe-collection-when-i-get-this-error-mute), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670248/boost-mutex-c-cli-problems/5670634#5670634), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585714/error-mutex-is-not-supported-when-compiling-with-clr-or-clrpure), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28447236/workaround-for-mutex-in-native-lib-for-cli-dll)

Comment: By the way @HansPassant you missed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359179/turn-off-clr-option-for-header-file-with-stdmutex?rq=1) one! Also from 5 years ago :-D

Comment: @WhozCraig so doing this, compiling the unmanaged C++ all together with /clr, am I missing the good old C++ compiler optimizations? Or is it still faster code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mixed-mode project can include both unmanaged C++ and managed C++/CLI code. Since `<mutex>` "*is not supported when compiling with `/clr`*" the code that requires it needs to be moved into a separate `.cpp` file set to compile *without* `/clr`. That can be done by adding a new `.cpp` file to the project, then changing the *Property Pages / Configuration Properties / C/C++ / General / Common Language RunTime Support* setting from `/clr` to *none* for that particular `.cpp` file (*not* for the entire project).

- The code must be moved to a separate file set to compile without `/clr` in its entirety. Just putting the code inside a `#pragma unmanaged` block in a file compiled with `/clr` will not work.
- If the project uses precompiled headers, the new file must be set to *not* use the precompiled header, since that one should *not* be shared between objects built with vs. without `/clr`.

Comment: I saw some 10 year old posts with this info, I was hoping for some modern solution but apparently there is no other solution.

Comment: @PedroFerreira Granted, C++/CLI is a bit rough around the edges, and I guess it will always be. But the alternatives for interop are a lot worse IMHO, even when counting these /clr idiosyncrasies.